# Excel File not opening up

Tags: python, excel

I have a python code that takes values from one excel file performs some calculations and stores them into another file. the record and output are huge. but today the output file got corrupted. as I don't have any backup.
The error I see is "We found a problem with some content in 'FileName.xlsx'.Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook"
I have also added some screenshots. I have tried some online fixes but that does not work.
Any help is much appreciated.

[Error notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWjmV.png)

Upon clicking 'Yes' it states that 'Excel' can not open the file format or the extension is not valid. Verify the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Comment: hey, have you tried reading the excel file through pandas?

Comment: Are you able to rename the output file and re-run your script on the input file to regenerate the output? It will be difficult to assist you without some more information from you, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: I am not sure what the issue could be. I have rerun the code after changing the output file name and path. and this time it has not given any error and output is saved in an excel file.